# SQL Server: set two or more records with the same value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two columns: `LABEL_ID` and `TYPE`.

```
LABEL_ID      TYPE
1234         Salad
1234         Dressing
4455         Croutons
5889         Salad
6574         Nuts
8845         Bacon Bits
8845         Salad
```

What I am looking to do is that if one `LABEL_ID` has a specific `TYPE` (=Salad), then set a third indicator column with the same value. IF `Type = Salad`, then set `IND = YES` for both records.

```
LABEL_ID      TYPE          IND
1234          Salad         YES
1234          Dressing      YES
4455          Croutons       NO
5889          SALAD         YES
6574          Nuts           NO
8845          Bacon Bits    YES
8845          Salad         YES
```

Comment: I suggest that whoever deleted the "wrong" answer please do not do that but add a comment as to why it was incorrect. Also to the commenter - DO NOT just say it was wrong but why it was wrong. It seemed fine to me and I'd like to know why it was wrong to use the CASE statement to answer the OP.

Comment: @rheitzman The answer was wrong because it would show 'YES' only for rows that have `Type = Salad`. That means row `1234, Dressing` will show 'NO'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
SELECT a.*,
CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT LABEL_ID FROM Table b 
                  WHERE a.Label_id = b.Label_id AND b.Type = 'Salad') THEN 'YES'
     ELSE 'NO' 
END [IND]
FROM Table a
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE t
SET
    IND = 'YES'
FROM your_table as t
INNER JOIN your_table as p on t.LABEL_ID = p.LABEL_ID
WHERE p.TYPE = 'Salad'
```